# how to parsing XML file

Tags: c#, xml, wpf

I have a file in that format

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AMG>
    <Include File="..."/> <!-- comment -->
    <Include File="...."/> <!-- comment -->

    <AMGmers Name="Auto">
        <Array Type="move" Name="move_name"/>
    </AMGmers>  

    <AMGmers Name="Black" Parent="Auto">
        <Attr Type="Color" Name="auto_Params"/>
    </AMGmers>
        <!-- comment -->

</AMG>
```

I have to get all name from `<AMGmers>`, and I have to check availability Parent.
I was trying to do so

```
XmlDocument doc1 = new XmlDocument();
doc1.Load("test.xml");
XmlNodeList elemList1 = doc1.GetElementsByTagName("Name");
```

Please help me understand.

Comment: Do you want to get `Auto` and `Black` ? or `move_name` and `auto_Params`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `<AMG>` is the root node and `<AMGmers>` tags are inside `<AMG>`, you can get all `<AMGmers>` tags using this syntax

```
XmlNodeList elemList1 = doc1.SelectNodes("AMG/AMGmers");
```

I assume you want to get the value of `Name` attribute from all `<AMGmers>` tags and check whether each `<AMGmers>` tag has `Parent` attribute, so this code should work

```
foreach (XmlNode node in elemList1)
{
    if (node.Attributes["Name"] != null)
    {
        string name = node.Attributes["Name"].Value;

        // do whatever you want with name
    }

    if (node.Attributes["Parent"] != null)
    {
        // logic when Parent attribute is present
        // node.Attributes["Parent"].Value is the value of Parent attribute
    }
    else
    {
        // logic when Parent attribute isn't present
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

If you want to get the `<Array>` nodes inside `<AMGmers>`, you can do so as below

```
foreach (XmlNode node in elemList1)
{
    XmlNodeList arrayNodes = node.SelectNodes("Array");
    foreach (XmlNode arrayNode in arrayNodes)
    {
        if (arrayNode.Attributes["Type"] != null)
        {
            // logic when Type attribute is present
            // arrayNode.Attributes["Type"].Value is the value of Type attribute
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2**

If you want to enumerate all nodes inside `<AMGmers>`, you can do so as below

```
foreach (XmlNode node in elemList1)
{
    foreach (XmlNode childNode in node.ChildNodes)
    {
        // do whatever you want with childNode
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much , everything works , please tell me how to get specific data from <AMGmers> to </AMGmers>

Comment: What specific data exactly? Can you give an example?

Comment: This data <Array Type="move" Name="move_name"/>

Comment: I'm sorry, but how to get all the data, because it can not only be array

Comment: It might look like   <AMGmers Name="Auto"> <Array Type="move" Name="move_name"/> <Attr Type="Color" Name="auto_Params"/> <Buff Type="Color" Name="auto_Params"/> </AMGmers>

Comment: Or i need to sort through each node?

Comment: See the EDIT 2 portion.